# Java.lang.NumberFormatException thrown

Tags: java, debugging, types, hex, long-integer

I am trying to write a program for converting positive binary inputs into hex.
Why am i getting this errors while compiling my binary to hex converter..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "148.0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
at BinToHex.convertbintohex(BinToHex.java:24)
at Test.main(Test.java:4)
```

Here is my BinToHex class

```
import java.io.*;


public class BinToHex {
    double tempDec,fractionpart;
    long longofintpart,templongDec;
    String inpu ="1001.01";
    String hexOutput,intpart,tempDecString,hex = null;

    static int i = 1;

    public void convertbintohex() {

        if (inpu.contains(".")) {
            int placesAfterPoint = inpu.length() - inpu.indexOf(".") - 1;//every thing
            long numerator = Long.parseLong(inpu.replace(".", ""), 2);//goes 
            double decimalOfInput = ((double) numerator) / (1L << placesAfterPoint);//alright  till here 


            while (true) {
                tempDec = decimalOfInput * 16;
                if ((int)tempDec == tempDec) {
                    tempDecString = String.valueOf(tempDec);
                    templongDec = Long.parseLong(tempDecString, 10);
                    hexOutput = Long.toHexString(templongDec);

                    break;
                } else {
                    intpart = String.valueOf((long)tempDec);
                    longofintpart = Long.valueOf(intpart).longValue();
                    if(i==1){
                        hex=Long.toHexString(longofintpart);
                        hexOutput = hex + ".";
                        i=i+1;
                    }else{
                        hexOutput = hexOutput + hex;
                    }
                    fractionpart = tempDec-(int)tempDec;
                    decimalOfInput = fractionpart;
                }
            }
        } else {
                // this part is ok
            tempDecString = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(inpu, 2));
            templongDec = Long.parseLong(tempDecString, 10);
            hexOutput = Long.toHexString(templongDec);
        }
        System.out.println(hexOutput);
    }
```

}

and my Test class..

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    BinToHex i = new BinToHex();
    i.convertbintohex();    
}
```

}

sorry for such a question ;-)
really need help

Comment: That's not a compiler error.

Comment: The String `148.0` cannot be parsed to a `Long`.

Comment: why can't the string be parsed into a long? what is the solution of this? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: You should review your `Number` and numeric primitive types.

Comment: tell me what to do? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 0):

Long.parseLong "Parses the string argument as a **signed long**".  148.0 is a double.

You're using a cast in the "if" statement, but not afterwards:

```
if ((int)tempDec == tempDec) {
    tempDecString = String.valueOf(tempDec);
    templongDec = Long.parseLong(tempDecString, 10);
```

instead, try:

```
if ((long)tempDec == tempDec) {
    tempDecString = String.valueOf((long)tempDec);
    templongDec = Long.parseLong(tempDecString, 10);
```

You're already doing that later on in the else statement, you just missed it above.  I think there are other issues in this code but this should answer the original question.